# Memory allocated by the ClientDataSet is not released even after you run the EmptyDataSet, Close, and even Free methods

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, delphi-6

I have an application that contains a `ClientDataSet` connected in a `DataSetProvider` that is connected in an `TIBQuery` (**Delphi 6**).

I run several queries and after each of them I run the EmptyDataSet, Close, and Free methods.

For example:

```pascal
procedure TAggregator.Load(ASql: string);
begin
  try
    FQry.SQL.Text := ASql;
    FCds.SetProvider(FDsp);
    FCds.Open;
    FCds.EmptyDataSet;
    FCds.Close;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      raise e;
  end;
end;
```

This is the two files from my minimal app sample to reproduce the problem:

```pascal
program CdsConsumptionTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  IBDatabase,
  uAggregator in 'uAggregator.pas';

var
  database: TIBDatabase;
  transaction: TIBTransaction;
  aggregator: TAggregator;
  tables: TStringList;
  index: integer;

begin
  try
    try
      database := TIBDatabase.Create(nil);
      transaction := TIBTransaction.Create(nil);
      try
        database.DefaultTransaction := transaction;
        database.Params.Values['user_name'] := 'SYSDBA';
        database.Params.Values['password'] := 'masterkey';
        database.SQLDialect := 3;
        database.LoginPrompt := false;
        database.DatabaseName := 'C:\bases\17011\BASE.GDB';

        tables := TStringList.Create;
        aggregator := TAggregator.Create(database);
        try
          database.GetTableNames(tables);

          Writeln('Connection successful!');
          Write('Press ENTER to continue ...');

          // After that you can see the memory being increased and no longer released
          Readln;

          for index := 0 to pred(tables.Count) do
          begin
            aggregator.Load('select * from ' + tables[index]);
          end;
        finally
          tables.Free;
          aggregator.Free;
        end;

      finally
        database.Free;
        transaction.Free;
      end;
    except
      on e:Exception do
      begin
        Writeln('');
        Writeln('ERROR! ' + e.Message);
        Writeln('');
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Write('Process completed! Press ENTER to exit ...');
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

and...

```pascal
unit uAggregator;

interface

uses
  IBQuery, DBClient, Provider, IBDatabase, SysUtils;

type
  TAggregator = class
  private
    FQry: TIBQuery;
    FCds: TClientDataSet;
    FDsp: TDataSetProvider;
  public
    constructor Create(AIBDatabase: TIBDatabase); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  public
    procedure Load(ASql: string);
  end;

implementation

{ TAgregador }

constructor TAggregator.Create(AIBDatabase: TIBDatabase);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FQry := TIBQuery.Create(nil);
  FQry.Database := AIBDatabase;

  FDsp := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
  FDsp.DataSet := FQry;

  FCds := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  FCds.SetProvider(FDsp);
  FCds.PacketRecords := -1;  
end;

destructor TAggregator.Destroy;
begin
  FCds.Free;
  FDsp.Free;
  FQry.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TAggregator.Load(ASql: string);
begin
  try
    FQry.SQL.Text := ASql;
    FCds.SetProvider(FDsp);
    FCds.Open;
    FCds.EmptyDataSet;
    FCds.Close;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      raise e;
  end;
end;

end.
```

When I start the app I see that a lot of memory is allocated.
After pressing ENTER to start the queries I see by the Windows Task Manager that the memory is being incremented and never released.
Until the process reaches the point where I need to press ENTER to terminate the application and until then the memory that was allocated (even after the Free of the ClientDataSet) is not released.

In this small example it does not prove to be a big problem.
But in my actual application this is being raised an Out Of Memory type exception.

How I can solve this problem?

---

## EDIT

Testing with FastMM4 I received the following report:

[image: FastMM4 Report]

That I do not understand.

Comment: If you don't have it already, get FastMM4 (https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4), and use it in you app with FullDebugMode set to true.  This should give you a better idea that TaskMan will of any memory your app is using and not releasing.

Comment: The concept of try/finally is to create before entering the try part.

Comment: Task Manager is not a reliable way to test memory use in your application. Also, freeing a component does not necessarily result in the memory being returned to the OS; the Delphi memory manager does not release it, as it presumes you're just going to use it again. Use a better means of evaluating memory use, as @MartynA suggests. (Also, if you'r'e concerned about memory use, you probably shouldn't be using an in-memory dataset in the firs t place. TClientDataset is designed to hold a reasonable amount of data, not a huge dataset.)

Comment: @MartynA, I tried with FastMM4, I used the FullDebugMode directive, but I could not understand the report it generated.

Comment: @KenWhite , about the quantity of data that the TClientDataSet supports, in this example I made it load all the data of the table (select * ..) just so that the error was generated, but my real case is loading few records. My real problem is the "Out Of Memory" error, and I'm using the data in memory because it needs performance in that process and the information is stored from one transaction to another (from one database connection to another).

Comment: Generate detailed map file and fastmm will give more stack information.